# Cassandra not starting due to unknown Column Family

Tags: cassandra

After adding/removing tables and views to a keyspace a got problems with inconsistency and error referring to tables previous deleted. We tried to restart cluster nodes, only resulting in the nodes not starting due to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown CF`.

The current error is thrown from a View that refers to a non existing table (The table do exist but has a new id). Is it possible to some how fix this when Cassandra is not running?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have a schema mismatch.  Verify first that you're running the same schema versions `nodetool describecluster` and make sure all nodes are reachable.

The only other time i've seen something like this is when you have corrupt data on a node.  In which case you'll want to `nodetool removenode` the appropriate node and provision a new one.

As an asside `MATERIALIZED VIEWS` are deprecated in 3.11 and will not be supported going forward.  I would suggest that you roll your own.